# how to make crumpets with bigger and more holes

Tags: bread, batter, additives

I make many batches of crumpets and although they taste okay, I can't seem to get enough holes. I've tried adding bi-carb at various stages of proving, but it doesn't do anything. I've also tried Cream of Tartar. Again, it didn't work. Does anyone have any ideas.
The recipe I use is as follows:
320g flour (maida is a plain white flour available here in India)
1 tablespoon instant dried yeast
1/2 teaspoon bi-carb of soda
1 teaspoon salt
1 teaspoon sugar
225ml warm milk
225ml warm water

Comment: Welcome! It may be a good idea to include your recipe and method in the question - sometimes a general tricky helps, sometimes a given recipe needs improvement. You can always [edit] your post. And as for all new users, I recommend you take the [tour] and browse through the [help] to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: I see you've added some information about the ingredients you used - which is very helpful, but it might help to add some information about the cooking process too (e.g. times and temperatures). Especially with crumpets, which get their bubbles through steam from cooking, it's relevant to know what process you're following there! :)

Comment: Hi Elisa, it turns out you are using a yeast dough. In that case, it is basically the same advice whether you are making bread or crumpets, so I closed it as a duplicate to the same question about bread. Don't mix soda or baking powder into yeast dough, that doesn't help.